# make_unique availability in Xcode5?

Tags: c++, c++11, xcode5

I was just trying to use make_unique function of c++11 on Xcode5.0.2,
The Clang version is

> Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

After checking `<memory>` It looks like it is not there. make_shared is.

I know this is C++14, but it was also one of the first function validated for c++14.
It is even in Visual :).

When will it be available?

Answer (score 5):

*Note: more a comment than an answer, but formatted code and comments do not mix.*

Unfortunately, no idea when it will be available; however you can easily define it yourself for now and just switch to the standard one later:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_unique(Args&&... args) -> std::unique_ptr<T>
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

That's it, contrary to `make_shared` there is no magic here because the benefit is *just* one of exception safety (tie together allocation and capture in `unique_ptr`) whereas `make_shared` bundles additional advantages (irrelevant to `unique_ptr`).

Answer (score 0):

[March 10, 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#5.x_series) with Xcode 5.1 with Clang based on LLVM 3.4svn which has full C++14 support. See https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html